# Mac app Notarization gives warning "Signature does not include a secure time stamp"

Tags: macos, code-signing, notarize

I am using few .dylib libraries in my mac osx app. While notarizing, i get notarized app (with Ready to distribute status), but its showing 2 warnings ,

1. "The binary is not signed."
2. "The signature does not include a secure time stamp.", for the libraries i have added.

I am using third party library "ivona" for text to speech, for which, these libraries are used. 
Now my question is

1. Is it safe to distribute these app, with such warning?
2. How can i add timeStamp for these library, to remove these warnings?

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBnvZ.png)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says the binary isn't signed. Did you sign it? Signing is a separate step from notarization.

Apple has some pretty reasonable documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues

That has example `codesign` commands. Specifically it's worth noting that you need the `--timestamp` option

Answer (score 0):

Adding those `.dylib` files to frameworks in my code directly helped me to solve the issue.